# Как путь к txt файлу python

Tags: python, ос, txt

мне требуется узнать путь к конкретному файлу по его имени, пробовал различные методы ,но так и не нашел искомого ,данная реализация дает путь к расположению запускаемого .py файла

```
import os
name='NameFile.txt'
p = os.path.abspath("")
print(p)
```

Comment: В смысле вы знаете только имя файла и вам нужно найти каталог, в котором он лежит? Ну `os.walk` например от корня обходить все каталоги, искать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
 r"E:\file_name.txt"
```